# Error 400 when trying to upload images to GraphCMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, formik, graphcms

I'm trying to upload an image when a form is submited, the problem comes when I try to send the image as a base64 to the upload endpoint.

```
// Form input for image uploads
<input
  name="main_image"
  type="file"
  accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp"
  onChange={(event) => {
   const file = event.target.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.result);
    setFieldValue("main_image", event.target.result); // This is what I send to the backend
   };

  if (file && file.type.match("image.*")) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // I send it as Base64 to show the image in the website
  }
}}
/>
```

When the form is submited it runs a function to start the image upload in the backend

```
// Backend function to upload image

const { image } = req.body;

  const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(
    image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/, ""),
    "base64"
  );

  form.append("fileUpload", imgBuffer);


  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.GRAPH_DOMAIN}/upload`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      authorization: "auth token",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: form,
  });

// Do stuff with the response
```

I've tried sending the image as a base64, but it doesn't work, the documentation only says to use `fs.createReadStream('path/to/file.png')` for non URL images, and sending the image as base64 as a URL doesn't work either.

Link to GraphCMS documentation: https://graphcms.com/docs/api-reference/content-api/assets#upload-by-file